# Javascript OnMouseOver by <tr> tag without fire by child element <td>

Tags: javascript

I set onmouseover on `<tr>`, but the mouseover will trigger whenever the mouse hover on every `<td>`, how to make it fire once when hover on   regardless the child element?

```
<tr id="result0" onmouseover="highlighttext(1,8)">
   <td class="paratd">1</td>
   <td class="keywordtd">PO</td>
   <td>Do you need to post registry?</td>
</tr>
```

when 1 hover at "1" count 1 mouseover, when i hover at "po
 count mouseover again (become 2 count now), when i hover at "Do you need to post registry?" again, it count again (3 count now).

Additional info: How i set the mouseover attribute:

```
newtr.setAttribute("onmouseover","highlighttext(1,"+j+")")
```

the j is for loop running number, just want to use it to pass parameter to highlighttext function.

Then this is how i code the highlighttext():

```
function highlighttext(wordtype,wordnum){
    console.log(wordtype,wordnum)

}
```

Update:
Well, i try to upload it at codepen but it end up treat me as spam..

Comment: Can you show your code that will make it easier to answer

Comment: This is very interesting question, too bad people downvote without understanding it.

Comment: edited the question with code, please check again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, mouseover and mouseout events will fire for every over/our interaction for child elements.

In your case you should use `onmouseenter` event which will not trigger multiple times for child nodes within same parent container:

```
<tr id="result0" onmouseenter="highlighttext(1,8)">
   <td class="paratd">1</td>
   <td class="keywordtd">PO</td>
   <td>Do you need to post registry?</td>
</tr>
```

Note, for better results depending on your styles, you might need to set `border-collapse: collapse;` on table.

Comment: Thanks! it work!